# How to save each segment as a separate file with DaVinci Resolve?

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have a movie imported into my project. The movie consists of several aikido techniques. I want to slice the movie with blade into several segments, each contains only one aikido technique.

Having cut the video, I want to save each segment into a separate file. 
How to accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the **deliver** tab and on the left click on the **file** menu. Above it yopu should see the checkboxes labelled **Render [ ] single clip [✓] Individual clips**. check the individual clips box, and then check the **Use Unique Filenames** box. This will output every clip in your sequence as a separate file, with a numeric suffix, eg *output_0001.mov, output_0002.mov…*

[image]

You can either use a custom name or base the name on the original source clip. (This is how you export files from a grade, so that they link to the original footage file.)

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in exporter with **individual clips** export doesn't give you processed audio or different layers rendered together. It just renders the source clips trimmed the way you put them in your timeline.

I had this problem and ended up making [MediaChopper](https://mediachopper.io/). It is a small utility program that lets you split the video files based on almost any data.

First, you render the whole video file as usual. Then you export the **Edit Index** from DaVinci Resolve.

Take these two things, put them in MediaChopper and select which segments you want.

Full disclosure: I made MediaChopper and would love to hear if it's useful for anyone.